# React Headless WordPress frontend not showing all posts

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, headless-cms

I'm working on a react frontent for a headless WordPress cms. Im running into an issue where not all posts are showing correctly. I have 100 posts, they are named post 100 - post 1. See screenshot posts 100 - post 91 are showing then it is showing post 80 - Post 1. so it is missing posts 90 - 81

Screenshots
Results:
[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Wordpress posts:
[image: Wordpress posts]

Below is my code:
main.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

app.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Blog from "./components/Blog";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Blog />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

blog.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";
import BlogPost from "./BlogPost";

const Blog = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);
  const postsPerPage = 10;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `http://headless-wordpress.test/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`,
        {
          params: {
            per_page: postsPerPage,
            page: page
          }
        }
      );
      const newPosts = response.data;
      setPosts((prevPosts) => {
        const uniquePosts = newPosts.filter((newPost) => (
          !prevPosts.some((prevPost) => prevPost.id === newPost.id)
        ));
        return [...prevPosts, ...uniquePosts];
      });
      setPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1);
      setHasMore(newPosts.length >= postsPerPage);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching posts:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <InfiniteScroll
      dataLength={posts.length}
      next={fetchPosts}
      hasMore={hasMore}
      loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
      endMessage={<p>No more posts to load.</p>}
    >
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <BlogPost key={post.id} post={post} />
      ))}
    </InfiniteScroll>
  );
};

export default Blog;
```

blogpost.jsx

```
import React from "react";

const BlogPost = ({ post }) => {
  return (
    <div className="blog-post">
      <h2 className="blog-title">{post.title.rendered}</h2>
      <div className="blog-content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content.rendered }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BlogPost;
```

sample of the data from http://headless-wordpress.test/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
https://gist.github.com/JamesTsetsekas/b8eb4e18b1db1165732953b286c5a44f

I was expecting all posts to show in order from newest to oldest with no duplications or skipping.